# IOS 5 - CUSTOM EMOJI ICONS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios5

As we all know IOS 5 is gonna bring us emoji keyboard for everyone.

1. My question is if there is any way to create an app that would install new custom made emoji icons?
2. Or is there a way to create totally new custom emoji keyboard so it can later be chosen from INTERNATIONAL KEYBOARD SETTINGS.

Any tips? Or sample source codes?

Comment: You might want to re-read your Apple Developer NDA and consider how important it is to you to keep your Apple Developer status ?

Answer (score 4):

Don't know if I'm right but the Emoji-Icons were created and added by Apple. These "Emoji-Apps" just activate the Emojis for you.

So it isn't and won't be possible to add new Emojis in iOS 5 or earlier. And as Sum already said, iOS 5 is still under NDA and StackOverflow disallow discussions about this.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do that, keyboards are buried deep into UIKit and you have no official means of modifying them without resorting to jailbreaking.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible within documented functions. You'd need to jailbreak to modify keyboards. Enabling a keyboard that was always there was easy. Adding custom keys? Not really do-able without a jailbreak. iOS 5 is under nda so you can't discuss it here

Answer (score 0):

The emoji keyboard (on iOS 5 [which we can't discuss here] and previous versions) is not available to customize (like other iOS keyboard) through the official SDK.

Not only that, but emoji is now a standardized part of Unicode, and therefore your could customize their look, but not much more: an apple should have to stay an apple.

Depending of the kind of communication your looking to accomplish, you'll have to resort to your own custom way to insert smileys and icons in your text.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot add the emoji in IOS same thing with Android.

But my suggestion is to add new emojis by copying and pasting the image just like what KIMOJI used.